# Azure function SQL Binding with Python V2 - No function.json for setup

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

I am developing a azure function on my local with python v2. I am trying to connect my local function to a local mysql db, but I can't because I don't have function.json file.

V2 model does not use funtion.json file. Where Shall I setup that data then?

When I read doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql-input?tabs=isolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-python#http-trigger-get-row-by-id-from-query-string-5 , which I am trying to follow, It tells you to setup some things in **function.json** file. However, **that file is only in python v1 programming model, but not in v2**.

Comment: Yes, Model V2 does not have `function.json`. bindings are defined inside the `function_app.py` file.  check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators&tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level#programming-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Vivek Vaibhav Shandilya for clarifying "Yes, Model V2 does not have function.json. bindings are defined inside the function_app.py file."

So simply solved it using mysql-connector-python (https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/) in my function_app.py file. Here is an example of what I have added:

```
import mysql.connector

def execute_query(query):
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="my_user",
        password="password",
        database="my_database"
    )
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently Python programming model v2 does not support `SQL Trigger` ,`SQL Input` , `SQL Output`.
When you create function using `func` command python model V2 is default selected.
and there is no option to select `SQL trigger`, `SQL Input`, `SQL Output` in model V2.

```
PS C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\VS code Folders\Python> func init --worker-runtime python
Found Python version 3.11.7 (py).
The new Python programming model is generally available. Learn more at https://aka.ms/pythonprogrammingmodel
Writing requirements.txt
Writing function_app.py
Writing .gitignore
Writing host.json
Writing local.settings.json
Writing C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\VS code Folders\Python\.vscode\extensions.json
```

[image]

```
PS C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\VS code Folders\Python> func new
Use the up/down arrow keys to select a template:
Blob trigger
CosmosDB trigger
EventGrid trigger
EventHub trigger
HTTP trigger
Queue trigger
ServiceBus Queue trigger
ServiceBus Topic trigger
Timer Trigger
```

[image]

## If you want to create in V1 model you need to mention model v1 in the command.

**`bash command`:**

```bash
func init --worker-runtime python --model v1
```

```bash
PS C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\VS code Folders\Python> func init --worker-runtime python --model v1
Found Python version 3.11.7 (py).

Writing requirements.txt
Writing getting_started.md
Writing .gitignore
Writing host.json
Writing local.settings.json
Writing C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\VS code Folders\Python\.vscode\extensions.json
```

[image]

```
PS C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\VS code Folders\Python> func new
Use the up/down arrow keys to select a template:
Azure Blob Storage trigger
Azure Cosmos DB trigger
Durable Functions activity
Durable Functions entity
Durable Functions HTTP starter
Durable Functions orchestrator
Azure Event Grid trigger
Azure Event Hub trigger
HTTP trigger
Kafka output
Kafka trigger
Azure Queue Storage trigger
RabbitMQ trigger
Azure Service Bus Queue trigger
Azure Service Bus Topic trigger
SQL Input Binding
SQL Output Binding
SQL Trigger
Timer trigger
```

[image]

```
PS C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\VS code Folders\Python> func new
Use the up/down arrow keys to select a template:SQL Trigger
Function name: [SqlTriggerBinding] sql_trigger
Writing C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\VS code Folders\Python\sql_trigger\readme.md
Writing C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\VS code Folders\Python\sql_trigger\__init__.py
Writing C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\VS code Folders\Python\sql_trigger\function.json
The function "sql_trigger" was created successfully from the "SQL Trigger" template.
```

[image]

**Result :**

new function will be created with `function.json` file

[image]

**`function.json`:**

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "changes",
      "type": "sqlTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "tableName": "[dbo].[table1]",
      "connectionStringSetting": "SqlConnectionString"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

**In VS Code :**

**`VS Code`:**

[image]

after selecting the programming language, option will be given to select model.

[image]